The number of lattice paths from (0, 0) to (2n, 3n) that never go above the diagonal
In discrete mathematics, a specific type of problem focuses on the number of lattice paths which go from one point A to another point B $\textbf{WITHOUT}$ going above the diagonal in the 2D plane. For instance, I was once told that the number of lattice paths which go from $A(0,0)$ to B$(n,n)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$ is the Catalan number $\displaystyle{C_n=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n-1}}$. The reason is given in the following picture.
First, the total number of lattice paths from $A(0,0)$ to B$(n,n)$ is $\displaystyle{\binom{2n}{n}}$. Then for an  arbitrary path that goes above the diagonal, we will denote the first point that goes above the diagonal as $C(x_0,y_0)$ (as the point circled in red in the picture).  By folding the path from $A(0,0)$ to $C(x_0,y_0)$ along the staight blue line $y=x+y_0-x_0$, and keeping the path from $C(x_0,y_0)$ to B$(n,n)$ unchanged, a new lattice path is formed from $A^{'}(-1,1)$ to $B(n,n)$. Therefore, an arbitrary lattice path from $A(0,0)$ to B$(n,n)$ that goes above the diagonal will correspond to a lattice path from $A^{'}(-1,1)$ to $B(n,n)$. Therefore, the number of paths that go above the diagonal is $\displaystyle{\binom{2n}{n-1}}$. Therefore, the number of paths that do not go above the diagonal is $\displaystyle{C_n=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n-1}}$.
However, the this method does not work when $B$ is not on the line $y=x$. For instance, when $B$ locates on $(2n,3n)$, the "folding" method appears unsuccessful. Is there a way of tackling this problem? More generally, when $B$ locates on $(an,bn)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$, is there a way of counting the total lattice paths that never go above the diagonal?

There is no closed formula for this problem. However the answer can be computed as a simple summation.

Theorem 11. The number of words in $D_{3/2}$ with length $5n$ or, equivalently, the number of generalized Dyck paths with slope $3/2$ and length $5n$, is
$$d_n= \sum_i \frac{1}{5n + i + 1} \binom{5n + 1}{n − i} \binom{5n + 2i}{i}. \tag{16}$$
© Philippe Duchon, On the enumeration and generation of generalized Dyck words.

Precomputed first elements of the sequence, formulae, code and and related links can be found at Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.
